# Reference to a Fragment after the life cycle has complete and restarted

Tags: android, android-fragments, runnable, fragment-lifecycle

I am trying to activate a runnable after 90 seconds. But if the user leaves the fragment and comes back, when the timer hit, it crashes.
Here is what I have so far.

when they click the button:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new RefreshRunnable(this), 1000 * 90);
```

RefreshRunnable class:

```
private static class RefreshRunnable extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements Runnable {
        private WeakReference<GridFragment> mFragmentRef;

        private RefreshRunnable(GridFragment fragment) {
            mFragmentRef = new WeakReference<GridFragment>(fragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.execute("");

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            mFragmentRef.get().getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID_GET, null, mFragmentRef.get().mGroupLoaderCallbacks);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

So in 90 seconds, it is supposed to activate a grid item. It will work if I stay on the fragment the whole 90 seconds. But if i leave and come back, when the 90 seconds hit, it will crash.

Comment: Your WeakReference is null at that point. You should always check to see if a WeakReference exists before accessing it.

Comment: so if it is null, how would i retrieve the reference to it?

Comment: You can't. That reference is lost.